# Animated <figcaption> Overlay deriving Width from Image

Tags: css, html, css-animations

I have the following CSS for animated slide-in caption overlays within `<figure>` elements:

```
figure {
    display:table;  /* to align width of figcaption to image width (hack?) */
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 auto 1em;
}
figure img {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
figcaption {
    display:table-caption;  /* maybe required for captions below image */
    caption-side:bottom;    /* ditto */
    position:absolute;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    color:#fff;
    padding:1rem;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:.9rem;
    opacity:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);
            transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);
    -webkit-transition:all 1.5s ease;
    transition:all 1.5s ease;
}
figure:hover figcaption {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
            transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

`display:table/-caption` were derived from previous solutions on SO to spare individual setting of width to the `<figure>` element, although with the caption showing below the image and no animation thrown into the game.

Removing `display:table-caption;` etc. for `figcaption` makes no difference, neither does adding `overflow:hidden` here.

HTML is simple:

```
<figure>
<img src="example.jpg" width="393" height="499" alt="example">
    <figcaption>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

In Chrome (and Safari 5/Windows) it works as expected, IE8 chokes on `<figure>` anyway.  However, in Firefox the figcaption shows sliding in with increasing background color from below the image. It might be a bug, although the behaviour is not without logic either.

It is not a big deal, for this is a micro site of just a few rather static pages, no database etc. Adding `style="width:xxxpx"` manually is easy. For the bigger sites we stick to javascript for compatibility with older browsers/IE anyway, so inserting `img` width to the wrapping `div` is painless. Anyhow, a clean automatic CSS solution would be welcome for future use.

TIA

**Edit:**

The code by Paulie_D did the trick, particularly the `dislay:inline-block`.

The only other change necessary for longer captions wrapping over several lines was to remove `padding:1rem;` from `figcaption` to a separate rule as right padding (and, depending on the amount of padding, part of the caption) would flow outside the image and the overflow be hidden:

```
figcaption > * {
    margin:1rem;
}
```

Comment: Sorry...what exactly is the question?...and a demo might be useful here.

Comment: "in Firefox the `figcaption` shows sliding in with increasing background color from below the image":on hover the caption shows **below** the image, then slides up until it rests as overlay on the image. In Chrome the caption is visible only as it slides **over** the image; below the image nothing becomes visible. That's how it should and how it also works in FF as long as `display:table` is not set, but `width` on `figure`.

Comment: So you want this ? - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rxRWwX

Comment: Thanks, Paulie_D. Your pen works OK in FF (and classic Opera). Will implement it later and check back with result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is functional in the same way in FF and Chrome. I hope it is what you are after.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
figure {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  /* shrink wrap */
}
figure img {
  display: block;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: .9rem;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-h-c-393-499-4.jpg" width="393" height="499" alt="example">
  <figcaption>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Many thanks, that was really quick! `display:inline-block` did the trick. Works like a charm.

Comment: As an aside I wonder if you had any particular reason for changing `bottom` to `top` and adding `width:100%`? Implementing your code step by step to get the most of it I could see no different behavior and finally reverted to mine as it seemed to work cross-browserwise, only leaving `width` as kind of insurance policy.

Comment: I find it easier to think top rather than bottom..no other reason.

Comment: Yep, usually it is. Only when sliding in something from the bottom or right I rather think from that point up :)